# List of MIME types for file types supporting DRM

Tags: mime-types, drm

I am writing a program to detect if a given file requires the use of some DRM software to decrypt it. Does anyone know of a comprehensive list of DRM file formats and their associated mime-types (or really any file metadata/header-info tha twould allow me to determine if it requires DRM).

Unfortunately neither the IANA, nor the following sites contained info about DRM-file formats:

- http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml
- http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/mime-types-htaccess.html